# Homepage white screen after migration server

Tags: homepage, migration

I migrate my client website from hosting to VPS.

i migrate by copying all file on root website folder and i export all table database.

all page / post and even dashboard (wp-login) i can access and login, but the homepage only shown **white screen**

many thing i did for troubleshooting but **still not solve** :

- rename and/or delete htaccess
- Changing Permalink setting
- Disabling All Plugins
- Increasing the Memory Limit

  `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '512M' );`
- Changing Front page displays to Static and choose pages.
- Replace Theme with a Default Theme
- Debug: true and display error ( nothing shown error message )

  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

  `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);`

Is there any suggestion i can try to solve my problem ?

I really appreciate for any suggestion.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's solved now.

actually it's simple problem. :D

By previous developer there is file name index.html. The solution is delete/rename the file index.html. See [printscreen](http://prntscr.com/gizcoz)